# Command 'SFDX: Run Apex Tests' resulted in an error (command 'sfdx.force.apex.test.run' not found)

Tags: vs-code, cli

I am learning Salesforce Apex development by taking a trailhead tutorial.

Tutorial: [Find and Fix Bugs with Apex Replay Debugger](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/find-and-fix-bugs-with-apex-replay-debugger)

I followed the tutorial along and got the following error when I try to call "SFDX: Run Apex Tests" in Visual Studio Code.

> Command 'SFDX: Run Apex Tests' resulted in an error (command
> 'sfdx.force.apex.test.run' not found)

[image]

[image]

I am able to run the tests in a terminal by the way.

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this error?
Thanks in advance.

My environment:

- MacBook Pro (13-inch, M1, 2020)
- OS: macOS Big Sur
- Virtual Studio Code Version: 1.62.3

Comment: Did you let the sfdx extensions load? It can take 30-60 seconds after opening a project folder. After all extensions load, it should normally work.

Comment: @sfdcfox I suspect that sfdx extensions do not install or load properly. But for your questions, the "run test command" does not work after waiting for more than 5 min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer my own question.

Everything works fine after I added Java home setting in setting.json of VS Code.

> "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home":
> "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk@11/11.0.12/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home",